# Decide consensus after finding location of unknown point with distances to two known points

Tags: r

Based on feedback from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77063827/find-location-of-unknown-point-with-distances-to-two-known-points, I created R code.

I am using a dataset that contains distances and Long/Lat in decimals, but I do not know the "origin" the researcher used to calculate the distances. I iterated over all pairs of locations to find the intersection of their great circles, and for each pair of distances there were two intersections. I combined all the results for the intersections, which were candidate locations for my "origin" point that the researcher used to calculate the distances. **However, now I have all the candidates, I see they are all very different, and I am unsure of what rationale I should use to "decide" on a consensus "origin" location?**

Create a small, sample dataframe:

```
group    <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
distance <- c(709, 2283, 5515, 3035, 4471) ##in km
long     <- c(20.5, 29.4, -14.3, 9.85, -5.5)
lat      <- c(-19.6, 1.6, 10.9, 2.3, 7.5)
Africa.groups <- data.frame(group, distance, long, lat)
> Africa.groups
  group distance  long   lat
1     A      709  20.5 -19.6
2     B     2283  29.4   1.6
3     C     5515 -14.3  10.9
4     D     3035  9.85   2.3
5     E     4471  -5.5   7.5
```

Specifically, I converted Long/Lat decimal into planar coordinates of the Chamberlin Trimetric equidistant projection for my area of interest (projectionwizard.org), buffered the two known points with their respective distance from the unknown point, and intersected the resulting two circles (note there are two solutions for each pair).

```
library(sf) ##load package for st_point, st_sfc, st_transform, st_buffer functions
library(sp) ##load package for SpatialLines and gIntersection functions

decimals <-  combn(nrow(Africa.groups), 2, FUN=\(x) {i <- x[1]; j <- x[2];   
  P0 <- as.numeric(Africa.groups[i, c("long", "lat")])
  P1 <- as.numeric(Africa.groups[j, c("long", "lat")])
  dists  <- Africa.groups[c(i,j), "distance"]*1000 ## in meters

  points <- st_sfc(st_point(P0), st_point(P1), crs = 4326)
  planar <- st_transform(x = points, crs = st_crs(points), 
                       aoi = c(-18.281389, -40.98, 56.25, 38.8225), 
                       dst = "+proj=chamb +lat_1=22 +lon_1=0 +lat_2=22 +lon_2=45 +lat_3=-22 +lon_3=22.5 +datum=WGS84 +type=crs")  ##transform from Long/Lat in decimals to planar 
  buffer  <- st_buffer(x = planar, dist = dists)

  # extract the feature coordinates of the polygon - we need to intersect lines, not polygons
  coordsB <- buffer[[1]]
  coordsC <- buffer[[2]]

  # create circles as lines
  lineB <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(coordsB[[1]]), "B")))
  lineC <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(coordsC[[1]]), "C")))

  # find intersections
  coords <- gIntersection(lineB, lineC)
  if (is.null(coords)) nums <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(NA, NA, NA, NA), ncol=2)) else 
  nums   <- as.data.frame(coords@bbox)
  coord  <- t(nums)

  # transform from planar back to Long/Lat in decimals
  back     <- st_sfc(st_point(as.numeric(coord[1,])), st_point(as.numeric(coord[2,])), 
                  crs =  "+proj=chamb +lat_1=22 +lon_1=0 +lat_2=22 +lon_2=45 +lat_3=-22 +lon_3=22.5 +datum=WGS84 +type=crs") 
  decimals <- st_transform(x = back, crs = st_crs(back), dst = "EPSG:4326")}  )

locations <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(decimals), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))
colnames(locations) <- c("LONG", "LAT")
```

Here are the resulting candidates for the "origin" location:

```
> locations
       LONG        LAT
1  16.44059 -18.925593
2  27.26761 -14.443967
3  20.33088 -26.066426
4  27.17353 -18.243687
5  15.87600 -24.433809
6  27.26761 -19.099996
7  18.80762 -25.825764
8  26.89103 -17.589895
9  26.41939 -19.057766
10 36.60939  21.085870
11 27.42443 -18.900711
12 29.04599  22.437865
13 25.66283 -18.819883
14 33.79646  21.760550
15 24.14394 -21.531683
16 36.60939   9.741317
17 26.41939 -18.357239
18 35.21485   3.595195
19 21.85686 -22.588342
20 35.21485  13.950634
```

It seems illogical to just take the mean of the Long and Lat:

```
avg.lon <- mean(locations[,1], na.rm=T)
avg.lat <- mean(locations[,2], na.rm=T)
```

Comment: What's your "model" for this? Is there a real single true (but unknown) "origin" and your data are noisy measurements that obscure the real origin? This is what statistics was invented for. If you can hypothesise a distribution of noise then you can derive an estimator for the true origin, and then that gives you a "best" prediction and an uncertainty. For simple statistical contexts that's the sample mean and sample variance, but here we don't have a hypothesis on how your data are generated from the origin, and you'll need to propose a statistical model to take this further.

Comment: @Spacedman There is no model here. I actually do have a dataset where the researcher (now deceased) calculated distances from some origin point to other locations. To use the data and to be able to replicate his results with a larger dataset, I need to know what he used as his "origin" point. So, there should be a single true origin.

Comment: So make up a model. Why do you get lots of different results for the origin? Are the distances or "known" locations subject to some measurement precision error? It seems like you've got intrinsic error somewhere given your results are over 30 degrees of latitude and 20 of longitude. Suppose measured distance is true distance plus random noise with an unknown spread, you can in theory compute how that spread relates to spread in the predicted origin point, and then combine all the predicted origin points to get a model-based estimate of the true point with uncertainty.

Comment: Mean of lat and mean of long is probably a bad idea, maybe you need to find the centroid of the points in spherical geometry - this would be independent of coordinate reference system and have the property of (I think) being the location with the minimum sum-of-squared distance to all the points....

Comment: I'm not sure the intersection method is a good idea here. Instead, try finding the single point that minimises the sum-of-square difference between its distance to the points and the distances given in the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it by finding the point that minimises the sum of square differences between the distances in the data and its distance to the points.

If the data were perfect, each circle intersection would meet at the true point solution and at a false point solution. In this case only two circle intersections would be necessary since the second one would eliminate the false solution.

Let's create the data as an `sf` spatial data frame with a distance column in metres:

```
library(sf)
group    <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
distance <- c(709, 2283, 5515, 3035, 4471) ##in km
long     <- c(20.5, 29.4, -14.3, 9.85, -5.5)
lat      <- c(-19.6, 1.6, 10.9, 2.3, 7.5)
Africa.groups <- data.frame(group, distance, long, lat)
pts = st_as_sf(Africa.groups, coords=c("long","lat"), crs=4326)
pts$distance = pts$distance * 1000
units(pts$distance) <- "m"
```

Then for investigation let's look at the intersection of the distance buffers. This is all being done in spherical geometry so there's no need to do coordinate transforms:

```
ptsb = st_buffer(pts, dist=pts$distance)
plot(ptsb$geometry)
plot(pts$geom, add=TRUE, pch=19) # add the points
```

[image]

From that we can see there's a lot of intersections along a roughly arc-shaped section east of the data points. The point with the smallest buffer ties it down to quite a small region, but hard to be objective from a visual device like this.

A more objective approach is to find the location that minimises the error between its distances to the points and the distances in the data. To compute this we first need a function that takes a point location and returns the root sum of squares of distance differences.

We can use this function to create such a function. Note it takes the point data as an argument and returns a function of an xy vector:

```
sumdr <- function(pts){
    f = function(xy){
        p = st_sfc(st_point(c(xy[1],xy[2])), crs=st_crs(pts))
        sqrt(sum((st_distance(p, pts)-pts$distance)^2))
    }
    f
}
```

Now we can create a distance function for our data and for example see what the root-square sum of distances is from any point, for example from Null Island:

```
sdp = sumdr(pts)
sdp(c(0,0))
# 5889099 [m]
sdp(c(20,10))
# 3993709 [m] - better location!
```

Now we use `optim` to find the x-y coordinate that minimises this total distance. From the plot we can give it a fair starting point and see where it ends up, and check the convergence state (0 means all went well and it found a stable minimum):

```
best = optim(c(25,-10), sdp)
best$par
# [1]  26.61110 -18.53444
best$convergence
# [1] 0
```

Now we can add that best location to the plot as a red dot:

```
points(best$par[1], best$par[2], pch=19, col="red")
```

[image]

and it does look like its found a really good candidate for the "true" single intersection point of the circles.

Let's do this on an interactive map with the `tmap` package:

```r
tm_shape(ptsb) + tm_borders() + tm_shape(pts) + tm_markers() +tm_shape(p)+tm_symbols(col="red")
```

[image]

The circles are a bit steppy because that's how they're calculated, but that has no effect on the location of the best location estimate at the red dot.

Note its also possible to compute an uncertainty on the point estimate using the hessian matrix but that is really only valid in a statistical likelihood setting. You could also compute this sum distance error over a grid to describe the uncertainty in the position but its not possible to quantify it without a statistical model underneath.

Comment: This is amazing. To clarify with the code from my question, I do not need to use ```combn``` to iterate through the pairs of locations to create points? I can just use the "raw" Long/Lat? Second, I do not need to convert from Lat/Long decimal to planar coordinates at all, which removes my back transformation, as well? I can stay in Long/Lat decimal?

Comment: I've not actually found the intersection points because they're not necessary for my method of finding the mystery location, but no, you could probably just use something like `st_buffer(pts, distances)` and then `st_intersection` to get all the overlap points in one go. `sf` uses spherical geometry if the CRS is lat-long, which is usually a better model for distance than a cartesian grid system, especially for large distances.

Comment: Just tried, yes you can get all the intersection points if: a) use a projection like yours (and add `+units=m` because otherwise `sf` doesn't know the units, and I'm assuming its metres, do check). b) create the buffers and cast to LINESTRING so you get the buffer as a perimeter line and not a polygon (using lat-long spherical geometry results in lots of bad intersections because of the steppy circles), c) use `st_intersection` and drop the self-intersections leaving you with just the points. If you want I can expand this in the answer above.

Comment: in your code ```tm_shape(ptsb) + tm_borders() + tm_shape(pts) + tm_markers() +tm_shape(p)+tm_symbols(col="red")``` how do I get ```tm_shape(p)```, since ```p``` was embedded within the function? The thematic plot won't work without it.

Comment: Yes sorry that was a bit rushed and I probably made another `p` elsewhere. Its the thing with coordinates in `best$par`, maybe: `p = st_sfc(st_point(best$par), crs=4326)` but I've not tested that.

Comment: That works great, thanks. For the thematic map, it appears to want something in ```tm_borders()```, at least that's how I'm interpreting this error in running the code in my above comment after specifying ```p```: "Error in if (borderlwd == 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Comment: to confirm it's ```tm_shape(pts) + tm_markers()``` this part of the code that throws the error

Comment: Sorry I really don't have time to go back and pick this all apart, and you are likely to want to map it some other way anyway, but the "optimal" point found by this algorithm is in `best$par` and all the other parts are there somewhere. If I get a chance I'll edit.